# Magmi: Group prices wont adjust

Tags: magento-1.9, import, grouped-products

Im using Magmi to import products and update the customer group prices, i have followed certain tutorials about how to set out the CSV files but the group price isnt changing, the price is so i know the import is working.

My CSV file looks like this

```
   | sku     |  group_price:Buying_Group|   price
   | TEST1234|  20                      |   40
```

The customer group is called Buying Group

I am not sure where i am going wrong, if anyone knows it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi - I've not tested this but think the group syntax is group_price:groupName

Comment: Also you have the grouprocessor module installed in magmi?

Comment: yea i have installed that plugin and also tick the group price box when i import it, so should i have buying_Group then as the groupName?

Comment: Hi Adam - I **Think it should be along the lines of group_price:buyingGroup or group_price:buyinggroup

Comment: ok i will give that a try a let you know if it worked

Comment: No didnt work unfortunately, i will keep trying new things though.